# How do I get information from other nested elements?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am struggling with using LINQ to <s>SQL</s> XML. I'm following examples and getting some good results.  However I ran into a problem and hope that someone can help me.

```
<root>
<MyItem  Host="00155DFF045C" LastName="HOUSTON" FirstName="WHITNEY" >
    <TimeStamp ComputerTime="02/07/2011 - 21:41:53.715">
        <Group Name="Group1">
            <Variable ID="1001" Value="Happy" >
            </Variable>
        </Group>
        <Group Name="Group2">
            <Variable ID="2000" Value="Monday" >
            </Variable>
            <Variable ID="2001" Value="Tuesday" >
            </Variable>
        </Group>
        <Group Name="Group3">
            <Variable ID="3000" Value="January" >
            </Variable>
            <Variable ID="3001" Value="February" >
            </Variable>
        </Group>
        <Group Name="Groupe4">
            <Variable ID="4001" Value="108.000000" >
            </Variable>
            <Variable ID="4002" Value="800" >
            </Variable>
        </Group>
        <Group Name="CustomGroup">
            <Variable ID="1001000" Value="1.000000" >
            </Variable>
        </Group>
    </TimeStamp>
</MyItem>
<MyItem>
...
...
</MyItem>
</root>
```

I correctly get info like `{Host="00155DFF045C" LastName="HOUSTON" FirstName="WHITNEY}` thanks to the tutorial.

But I need to get some more information.  How can I retrieve `Value` of the Variable element with `ID="4001"` which belongs to `Groupe4`?

My current code is:

```
XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
var toto = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("MyItem").Take(10)
           orderby tweet.Element("TimeStamp").Attribute("ComputerTime").Value descending
           select new History {
               DisplayName = tweet.Attribute("PatientFirstName").Value + " " +
                             tweet.Attribute("PatientLastName").Value
           };
```

With this code, I can correctly get value for `DisplayName`.  I would like to get value of variable `4001`, i.e., value `108.0000`.

Comment: Do you have any code written down so far?  It would make helping you know how to do it, easier to do.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I just updat my initial poste with my current code. Hope you can help me :)

Comment: If you have some source code you'd like to format, just paste it in and indent it with four spaces. It will be displayed nicely for you.  Just be sure to adjust it afterwords so it is readable.  :)

Comment: Thx so much, it simply works with you gave me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to a particular element, you can get values from any of its nested elements using the `Element()` or `Attribute()` methods.  You can get a list of these using `Elements()` or `Attributes()` to perform LINQ queries on them.  Assuming we have a reference to the root element, you can get the following information:

```
XElement root = ...;
XElement myItem = root.Element("MyItem");               // get the first "MyItem" element
string Host = myItem.Attribute("Host").Value;           // get value of "Host" attribute
string LastName = myItem.Attribute("LastName").Value;   // get value of "LastName" attribute
string FirstName = myItem.Attribute("FirstName").Value; // get value of "FirstName" attribute

// find "Groupe4"
XElement Groupe4 = (from g in myItem.Element("TimeStamp")
                                    .Elements("Group")
                    where g.Attribute("Name").Value == "Groupe4"
                    select g)   // only one element should be found
                   .Single();   // assign that element to variable Groupe4

// Get Value of Variable with ID = 4001
double Value4001 = (from v in Groupe4.Elements("Variable") // of all Variable elements
                    where (int)v.Attribute("ID") == 4001   // choose elements where ID = 4001
                    select (double)v.Attribute("Value"))   // select the Value
                   .Single();                              // assign that value to variable Value 4001
```

So to apply that to your query, you can do something like this:

```
XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
var id = 4001;   // the ID to find
var toto = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("MyItem")
                                  .Take(10)
           orderby (DateTime)tweet.Element("TimeStamp")
                                  .Attribute("ComputerTime") descending
           select new History {
               DisplayName = String.Format("{0} {1}",
                   tweet.Attribute("PatientFirstName").Value,
                   tweet.Attribute("PatientLastName").Value),

               // find the Variable with matching ID and get its Value as a double
               Value = (from v in tweet.Descendants("Variable")
                        where (int)v.Attribute("ID") == id
                        select (double)v.Attribute("Value"))
                       .Single()
           };
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have and `XElement` variable named `myItemElement`,

```
     myItemElement
            .Element("TimeStamp")
            .Elements("Group")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("Name") != null && x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Groupe4")
            .Elements("Variable")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("ID") != null && x.Attribute("ID").Value == "4001")
            .Attribute("Value").Value;
```

Comment: Hi Smartcaveman, you solution also works great ! Many thx to both of you.